# Find the norm of orthogonal projection of the vector y to the subspaces $span(x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> In the euclidean space $(X, \left\langle \cdot , \cdot\right\rangle)$ is orthonormal system $u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$ and vectors $x=u_{1}-2u{2}+2u_{3}$, $y=u_{1}+3u_{2}+2u_{3}$. Give the norm of orthogonal projection of the vector y to the subspaces $span(x)$.

My try:
 $\frac{\left\langle x,y\right\rangle)x}{\left\langle x,x\right\rangle)}=\frac{-x}{9}$
$||\frac{-x}{9}||=\frac{-1}{9}\left\langle x,x\right\rangle)=-1$
$span(x)$ is a one vector so it is a orthogonal basic but when I insert into the pattern I get the wrong answer because the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.
Can you help me and talk where I have a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good sanity check to keep in mind: norms are always nonnegative.

$$\|-x/9\| = \frac{1}{9} \|x\| = \frac{1}{9} \sqrt{1^2 + (-2)^2 + 2^2} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: So I can just remove minus like you?

Comment: @VirtualUser Yes, but you should understand why you may.